# Python: operator overloading unexpected output?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
 class point():
     def __init__(self,x=0,y=0):
         self.x=x
         self.y=y
     def __add__(self,other):
         x = self.x + other.x
         y = self.y + other.y
         return point(x,y)     

p1=point(3,6) 
p2=point(-1,4) 
print p1 
print p2 
d=p1+p2 
print 'the summation is',d
```

Expected output:

```
3,6
-1,4
2,10
```

Actually Output: (not really, but making the point)

```
<__main__.point instance at 0xdeadbeef1234>
<__main__.point instance at 0xdeadbeef1445>
<__main__.point instance at 0xdeadbeef1233>
```

Comment: Please fix your code. I'm not sure where those last lines are supposed to go.

Comment: @MorganThrapp - Wouldn't they go on the same level as the class?

Comment: What is unexpected about the output?  What output do you expect?

Comment: i want to add the points instead of adding locations of instance..

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do, or how the above code differs from what you want.

Comment: What output does the code provide for you, and what output do you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class works fine; you simply need to define a `__str__` method so that you see something other than the default representation of a class instance when you print it. One possibility:

```
def __str__(self):
    return '({0}, {1})'.format(self.x, self.y)
```

Even without that, you can see that `d` is the instance you want:

```
print d.x   # Outputs 2
print d.y   # Outputs 10
```

You might also want to define a `__repr__` function for debugging:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return 'Point(x={0}, y={1})'.format(self.x, self.y)
```

Comment: return '({0}, {1})'.format(self.x, self.y) can you explain this more briefly

Comment: `__str__` is called whenever your object is passed to the `str` function, or when it is used as an argument to the print function. The `format` method simply uses its arguments to replace any `{}` placeholders in the invoking string.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use **str** function in your class to see the values otherwise it just prints the memory address of that instance.

So, final code is:

```
class point():
    def __init__(self,x=0,y=0):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y

    def __str__(self):
        return 'point (%d, %d)' % (self.x, self.y)    

    def __add__(self,other):
        x = self.x + other.x
        y = self.y + other.y
        return point(x,y)     

p1=point(3,6) 
p2=point(-1,4) 
print p1 
print p2 
d=p1+p2 
print'the summation is',d
```